Historical forecast in time series libraries
I have been using Darts, where there is a very nice historical forecast functionality, and also nixtla's neuralforecast library. The latter does have cross-validation, which can mimick a historical forecast, but is bog-slow (unlike the other parts of nixtla's library, which are very speedy, and allow for a lot more customization than Darts). Any ideas of what the "right way" to do this is?

I don't use DARTS, but I am currently deploying a large scale forecasting framework at my job - using neuralforecast. Typically, I cut about 75% of my data as a train set, then define the neuralforecast object, then train it on that and predict on the remanining 25 (using the horizon at the test size length. I then retrain on the full dataset

Right, but saying 'nf.predict(X_test)' will only predict at the end of the test period. If you want to make a prediction at every point in X_test, this takes a VERY long time.

I don't think this is necessarily the way you want to do it though - NeuralForecast has robust support for a set horizon length. You don't really need to make point forecasts
